# PHP sdk - redirection error

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website in which I have the following files :-
index.php - homepage

f-login.php - page which redirects user to facebook to ask for permissions

add.php - which is given below - this page checks if the user is old or new. If the user is new, it redirects the page to username-choice.php or else it redirects the user to the main page after setting the required cookies.

username-choice.php - This page is for the NEW user to choose a username for himself. If the cookie - "tempuid" is set, it shows the correct page or else it shows an error page that "COOKIES ARE NOT ENABLED!"

The problem is that in the username-choice.php page the error message shows up. I cannot understand the problem. I have given my code for the add.php page. Please tell me what's wrong. Any help shall be appreciated.

The following is my add.php page :-

```
<?php
include "config.php"; /* contains mysqli_connect */
require "src/facebook.php"; /* for facebook login php-sdk */
include "app_details.php"; /* app-id and secret */
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);/* ERROR TO BE DISPLAYED */
    $user = null;
  }
}

$uid=$user_profile['id'];
$email=$user_profile['email'];
$fullname = $user_profile['name'];
$birthday = $user_profile['birthday'];

if($uid==null){
echo "Sanp! Something went wrong";
}

$n=0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE UID='$uid'");
/* TO CHECK IF THE USER IS NEW OR OLD*/
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$n++;
$username=$row['Username'];
$ppic=$row['Ppic_url'];
  }

if($n>0)
{

  $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
  setcookie("name"  , "$fullname", $expire);
  setcookie("uid"  , "$uid", $expire);
  setcookie("logintype", "facebook", $expire);
  setcookie("username", "$username", $expire);
  setcookie("ppic", "$ppic", $expire);
header("Location: http://mysite.com");
exit;
}
else if($n==0)
{

  $expire=time()+60*60*24*30*365;
  setcookie("tempname", "$fullname", $expire);
  setcookie("tempuid"  , "$uid", $expire);
  setcookie("tempemail", "$email", $expire);
  setcookie("tempbday", "$birthday", $expire);
  setcookie("tempppic", "$ppic", $expire);

header("Location: http://mysite.com/username-choice");
exit();

mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the program is going into the last if statement. Now, your webpage can display "COOKIES NOT ENABLED" only if the uid is null. So, according to me the $uid is null.

Comment: yes! that was the answer. I changed my hosting service and the problem was solved.